# Null-pointer Exception related to HttpServletResponse

Tags: jsp, nullpointerexception, liferay, portlet

I want to open a file from my web application.
I have a jsp, in this code when I click the button it should open a file,
my code jsp (specially javascript code) calls java code but I have an error: `Null-pointer Exception`

I think that this error is normally because I make the varaible `response` as `null`,
but I don't know when I should fill the `response` (`HttpServletResponse response`)

My JSP code is as follows:

```
<div id="pieces" class="baliseDiv"> 
    <fieldset style="padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;">
        <legend align="top">
            <util:message key="operateur.section.pieces.title" />
        </legend>

    <grid:view name="PieceRattacheList_view">
        <grid:search position="top" align="right" width="200"
                iconClass="icon-zoom" />

        <grid:actionsbar>
            <grid:action id="pieceRattacheList_add" type="button"
                    textkey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.action.pieceRattacheList_add.title"
                    tooltipkey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.action.pieceRattacheList_add.description"
                    iconClass="icon-form-add" onclick="action_pieceRattacheList_add" />

            <grid:action id="pieceRattacheList_add_Split" type="splitbar" />
        </grid:actionsbar>

        <grid:pagingbar pageSize="10" displayInfo="true">
        </grid:pagingbar>

        <grid:table name="PieceRattacheList_Tab" list="pieceRattacheList"
                titlekey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.title"
                formbean="DossierJuridiquePortletBean" recordForm="false"
                clicksToEdit="1" collapsible="true" closable="true" render="true">

            <grid:repository id="pieceRattacheList.pieceRattacheList"
                    classpath="com.dq.foprodex.web.repository.DossierJuridiqueRepository" />

            <grid:record id="attachementEntity" idProperty="id"
                    defaultSortColumn="nomfrPiece" defaultSortDir="ASC"
                    title="Enregistrement" columnCount="2"
                    iconClass="icon-edit-record"
                    recordClass="com.dq.foprodex.web.entity.AttachementEntity"
                    windowmodal="false">
                <grid:property name="id" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="idElement" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="idTable" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="idGuid" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="nomfrPiece" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="nomarPiece" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="etat" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="fo" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="df" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="agBack" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="respBack" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="pdg" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="idType" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="libType" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="respRattach" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="dateRattach" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="nbreRappel" type="Integer" />
                <grid:property name="dateDernRappel" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="dateDemComp" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="dateDepotComp" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="idAvis" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="libAvis" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="comm" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="app" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="dateApp" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="avisColumn" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="motif" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="rattachement" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="actiondocumentdiffuser" type="String" />
                <grid:property name="form" />
            </grid:record>

            <grid:column property="nomfrPiece"
                    titlekey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.column.nomfrPiece.title"
                    sortable="true" resizable="true" menuDisabled="false" width="20">
            </grid:column>
            <grid:column property="rattachement"
                    titlekey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.column.rattachement.title"
                    sortable="true" resizable="true" menuDisabled="false" width="40">
            </grid:column>
            <grid:column property="respRattach"
                    titlekey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.column.respRattach.title"
                    sortable="true" resizable="true" menuDisabled="false" width="40">
            </grid:column>
            <grid:column property="dateRattach"
                    titlekey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.column.dateRattach.title"
                    sortable="true" resizable="true" menuDisabled="false" width="40">
            </grid:column>
            <grid:column property="nbreRappel"
                    titlekey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.column.nbreRappel.title"
                    sortable="true" resizable="true" menuDisabled="false" width="40">
            </grid:column>
            <grid:column property="dateDernRappel"
                    titlekey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.column.dateDernRappel.title"
                    sortable="true" resizable="true" menuDisabled="false" width="40">
            </grid:column>
            <grid:column property="etat"
                    titlekey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.column.etat.title"
                    sortable="true" resizable="true" menuDisabled="false" width="40">
            </grid:column>
            <grid:column property="comm"
                    titlekey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.column.comm.title"
                    sortable="true" resizable="true" menuDisabled="false" width="40">
            </grid:column>

            <grid:column property="rowaction2" width="5">
                <grid:rowaction id="piece"
                        tooltipkey="operateur.list.pieceRattacheList.action.pieceRattacheList_update1.title"
                        iconClass="icon-form-key1"
                        onclick="action_consultDoc"/>
            </grid:column>
        </grid:table>
    </grid:view>

    <br>

    </fieldset>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function action_consultDoc(grid, record, row, col) {
    operateurService.consultDocService(Ext.getCmp('userId').getValue(),record.get('id'), {
        callback : function(responseEntity) {

        }
    });
}
</script>
```

The method `consultDocService` of the  class `operateurService` is:

```
public void consultDocService(String userid, String id) {

    DossierJuridiqueManager dossierJuridiqueManager =
            (DossierJuridiqueManager) PortalUtil.getBean(DossierJuridiqueManager.managerid);

    try {
        dossierJuridiqueManager.consultDoc(null, null, userid, id);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code `consultDoc` of my class `DossierJuridiqueManager`:

```
public ResponseEntity consultDoc(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String userid, String id)
        throws Exception {
    System.out.println("the ids"+id);
    List<AttachementEntity> attachements = attachementDAO.getAttachementList(id);
    AttachementEntity attachementEntity=new AttachementEntity();
    attachementEntity=attachements.get(0);
    String guid=attachementEntity.getIdGuid();

    P8Connector connector = new P8Connector(TypeEnum.CE.value(), "gcd admin","C:/properties/");
    System.out.println("verif " + connector.getConnection());

    GetDocumentsListInFolder getDocumentsListInFolder = new GetDocumentsListInFolder();
    List<Document> list = new ArrayList<Document>();

    list = getDocumentsListInFolder.execute(connector, "/chemin", "1");

    int length = 0;
    ServletOutputStream op = response.getOutputStream();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Document doc = (Document) list.get(i);

        String h = doc.get_Id().toString();
        if(h.equals(guid))
        {
            GetDocumentContent c = new GetDocumentContent();

            byte[] is1 = c.execute(connector, doc);

            byte[] bbuf = new byte[1024];
            InputStream is3 = new ByteArrayInputStream(is1);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(is3);

            while ((in != null) && ((length = in.read(bbuf)) != -1)) {
                op.write(bbuf, 0, length);
            }

            in.close();
            op.flush();
            op.close();
        }
    }

    return new ResponseEntity();
}
```

the error `NullPointerException` is related to this line:

```
ServletOutputStream op = response.getOutputStream();
```

and this is because I make `response` to `null` through this code :

```
dossierJuridiqueManager.consultDoc(null,null, userid, id);
```

But when should I fill the `response`?

Comment: you can't create (___fill___) a response instance, it is the servlet-container that does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a controller somewhere which is calling your service, right? So you could pass your Response object through the service to the DossierJuridiqueManager from the handler method in your controller.

It would probably be better to return athe file contents from the DossierJuridiqueManager class though and do the I/O work in the Controller. This would keep the Response in the Controller where it belongs.